# Automatically remove referencing objects on deletion by mongoengine in django

Tags: python, django, reference, mongoengine

I was practicing to use mongoengine in django.

```
class RelativeTable(Document):
    user = fields.ReferenceField(CustomUser)
    device = fields.ReferenceField(Device, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)

    meta = {
        'collection': 'relative_table',
        'allow_inheritance': True,
        'indexes': [
            {'fields': ['user'], 'unique': True, 'sparse': True},
            {'fields': ['device'], 'unique': True, 'sparse': True},
        ]
    }
```

Through multiple times to practice. According to the above by my definition for Document, I find when I delete device, it will RelativeTable at same time. So, do I do the right thing?

If I define `user` field its `reverse_delete_rule` is `CASCADE` in `RelativeTable`, would it also has auto deleted when I delete its relative `user`?

[deleting-embeddeddocument-with-filefield-from-listfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257345/deleting-embeddeddocument-with-filefield-from-listfield)

[mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your device field of `RelativeTable` document sets `reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE`, it means if corresponding Device is deleted, the `RelativeTable` object will be deleted at the same time.

It's similar to MySQL features. When you use SQL to define relationship field, for examples, ManyToManyField, OneToOneField, ForeignKey.
A is bind with B. B is deleted, A is also deleted.